# LINQ XML file parsing

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to parse the below XML data to get the values of **Name** and **Total** for each **MetricResponse**

```
<MetricResponses xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MetricResponse>
    <Code>Success</Code>
    <Data>
       <DisplayName>CPU Time</DisplayName>
       <EndTime>2013-04-16T17:10:37.6101155Z</EndTime>
       <Name>CpuTime</Name>
       <PrimaryAggregationType>Total</PrimaryAggregationType>
       <StartTime>2013-04-16T17:00:00Z</StartTime>
       <TimeGrain>PT1H</TimeGrain>
       <Unit>Milliseconds</Unit>
       <Values>
         <MetricSample>
           <Count>1</Count>
           <Maximum i:nil="true" />
           <Minimum i:nil="true" />
           <TimeCreated>2013-04-16T17:00:00Z</TimeCreated>
           <Total>390</Total>
       </MetricSample>
     </Values>
  </Data>
<Message />
</MetricResponse>
```

I have written the following LINQ query for it:

```
  XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure";
  var metrics = from b in doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "MetricResponse")
                select new
                {
                    name=b.Element(ns+"Data").Element(ns+"Name"),
                    total=b.Element(ns+"Data").Element(ns+"Values").Element(ns+"MetricSample").Element(ns+"Total")
                };
```

But when I get a **NullReferenceException** when I am looping through **metrics**. The query works fine for getting the **Name** value and the exception occurs for **Total** expression.

Comment: Maybe some `<MetricRespone>` elements doesn't have `<Total>` descendant element, can you verify this?

Comment: All `<MetricResponse>` elements have a `<Total>` element under <Values>. This is the XML data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn166964.aspx

Comment: Yes, but your code doesn't throw exception given XML from that MSDN link : https://dotnetfiddle.net/V4EqPU

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)